# Вывод валюты из парсинга

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Нашел таблицу по классу, далее нашел в ней все `td` с определенным классом, в которой хранится валюта:

```
<table class="table-auto mfm-responsive-table mfm-collapse-tr mfm-table mfcur-table-lg mfcur-table-lg-nbu ">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="row--collapse">
          <td class="responsive-hide td-collapsed mfm-text-nowrap mfm-text-right" data-title="Курс НБУ">
            26.3884<span class="mfm-text-grey">2700</span>
            <span class="mfm-table-trend mfm-hover-show icon-down-open">-0.03351800</span>
          </td>
          <td class="responsive-hide td-collapsed mfm-text-nowrap mfm-text-right" data-title="Курс НБУ">
            29.5207<span class="mfm-text-grey">3300</span>
            <span class="mfm-table-trend mfm-hover-show icon-down-open">-0.24358800</span>
          </td>
          <!--и так далее-->
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Вот мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://minfin.com.ua/currency/nbu/'

source = requests.get(url)
main_text = source.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_text)

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table-auto'})
tr = table.findAll('td', {'class': 'responsive-hide'})
```

Теперь нужно, чтобы циклом выводилось только `26.38` (с первой `td`), `29.52` (cо второй) итд.

Как мне это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

r = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]

res = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 0].str.extract(r"^(\d+\.\d+)")[0], errors="coerce").dropna()
```

---

результат:

```
In [86]: res
Out[86]:
0    26.3884
1    29.5207
2     0.4101
3     6.9310
4    26.4167
5    33.0198
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

округленный:

```
In [87]: res.round(2)
Out[87]:
0    26.39
1    29.52
2     0.41
3     6.93
4    26.42
5    33.02
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

в виде списка:

```
In [88]: res.round(2).to_list()
Out[88]: [26.39, 29.52, 0.41, 6.93, 26.42, 33.02]
```

Comment: А как этот NaN в конце убрать?, на  сайте там только 6 значений, а 7 пустая строка..

Comment: @MaxKarrtopelka, смотрите в исправленном ответе...

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь API от НБУ, так как Ваш сайт может поменять внешний вид, и через полгода Ваш код внезапно не будет работать.

```
import urllib
import json
import datetime
currencyname = "USD"# введите нужную валюту (заглавными буквами)
# https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?valcode=EUR&date=20181030&json - так должен выглядеть запрос
todaydate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
URL= 'https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?valcode=' + currencyname + '&date=' + todaydate + '&json'
content = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
rate = json.load(content)[0]['rate']
```

Более подробно про API от НБУ можно почитать на странице НБУ: https://bank.gov.ua/control/uk/publish/article?art_id=38441973

Comment: хорошая идея !  :-)

Comment: да мне в принципе не суть важно именно валюту от НБУ, я хотел вообще иметь общее понятие парсинга...